# Use other Part instead of TitlePart in menu

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have a menu that has alot of query links. That will generate a good menu with the content of the TitlePart as the text.

I would like to use another parts field, that I have made, instead of the text in the TitlePart. Only in the menu and not on the contents page.

Is there a possibility to modify some module in order to achive this or is there a placement I can use to solve the problem??

Comment: Can you show us what you currently have in place? It may not be clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by inserting this

```
protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context)
    {
        var part = context.ContentItem.As<ReferenceCompanyPart>();

        if (part != null && part.CompanyName!= null && part.CompanyName != "") {
            context.Metadata.DisplayText = part.CompanyName;
        }
        else {
            var titlepart = context.ContentItem.As<ITitleAspect>();
            context.Metadata.DisplayText = titlepart != null ? titlepart.Title : "";
        }
    }
```

Then my ReferenceCompanyName was used insted of the TitlePart in the menu